# Duplicating an entire RDS instance PostgreSQL DB to another DB within the same instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

I'm trying to create a new DB (as a perfect copy of an existing RDS Instance DB, including data) when developers open a pull request. Since it's temporary, I need it to be created as fast as possible, and therefore I would not want to create a new instance.

What would be the fastest way to duplicate that DB to another one in the same RDS instance, and then delete it later after the pull request is merged?

I looked and found a plethora of ways: `pg_dump`, `pg_dumpall`, `pg_basebackup`, etc.

Comment: Use the source database as a template.

Comment: Would that copy all the data as well?